# SQL Server mail variable usage

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I want to use send mail utility on SQL Server where the recipients variable (@recipients) should take a formatted string as value. I want to show an example below:

```
EXEC msdb.dbo.sp_send_dbmail  
    @profile_name = 'Mail Profile',
    @recipients = Right('domain/user@company.com',
                         CHARINDEX('/',reverse('domain/user@company.com'))-1),
    @body = 'TEST MESSAGE',
    @subject = 'Automated Success Message'
```

But when I execute the above statement the error message appears:  Incorrect syntax near the keyword `Right`

Answer (score 5):

You can't pass an expression to am SP as a parameter. You have to pass a literal value or a variable. You'll need to declare a variable first, set it's value and then pass it as the parameter:

```
DECLARE @recipients nvarchar(255);
SET @recipients = RIGHT('domain/user@company.com', CHARINDEX('/', REVERSE('domain/user@company.com')) - 1);

EXEC msdb.dbo.sp_send_dbmail @profile_name = 'Mail Profile',
                             @recipients = @recipients,
                             @body = 'TEST MESSAGE',
                             @subject = 'Automated Success Message';
```